# Adding a String from a List inside another String

Tags: javascript

I have a `List<Object>` that is being sent, and inside each of its objects, there’s a string parameter `userFullName`.

Then I have this (I’ll use `%%` to enclose that which I do not know how to code right):

```
var userDetails = AJS.$("<h1/>").text("Hello %userFullName%! Welcome!");
```

This is my list:

```
args.weekData.list
```

How do I grab the parameter inside the object on the List (like in Java: `list[0].userFullName`) and add it to the `userDetails` String?

Comment: `args.weekData.list[0].userFullName`?

Comment: Dang, that worked, thanks. I red somewhere that in JS you'r supposed to use <> instead of [], so since that did not work, I came here hehe.

But thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
var userDetails = AJS.$("<h1/>").text("Hello " + args.weekData.list[0].userFullName + "! Welcome!");
```

Use `+` for string concatenation with JS

Comment: You could also use 'document.createTextNode(args.weekData.list[0])' instead of string concat, but either method is fine.